Serilog categorized multiple Sinks
I want to separate my logs in three different parts. Searched for logging libraries and the best one I found is Serilog.

write http request logs to daily rolling txt files.
write logs containing exceptions to Seq.
write all logs except http request logs to a local SQLite database (for users access).

Used the following code but nothing works:
new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.WithExceptionDetails(new DestructuringOptionsBuilder()
.WithDefaultDestructurers()
.WithRootName("Message").WithRootName("Exception").WithRootName("Exception"))
.Enrich.WithProperty("App.Version", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version?.ToString() ?? "0.0.0.0")
.Enrich.WithMachineName()
.Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
            .WriteTo.SQLite(GetFilePath("logs.db"))
            .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource("Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware"))
            .WriteTo.File(
                GetFilePath("access.log"),
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                retainedFileCountLimit: 31
            )
            .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(LogEvent => LogEvent.Exception != null)
            .WriteTo.Seq("https://mylogger.appserver.com/")

Removed second filter (request logs) and now it just writes exception logs in both Seq and local SQLite db.

did you chop the tail off this message,  or is it missing a CreateLogger and/or assigning ti to Log.Logger? When you say nothing works, it's worth checking things like that

You could use "sub logger" to configure different filter for each sink like following:
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails(new DestructuringOptionsBuilder()
                .WithDefaultDestructurers()
                .WithRootName("Message").WithRootName("Exception").WithRootName("Exception"))
                .Enrich.WithProperty("App.Version", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version?.ToString() ?? "0.0.0.0")
                .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                .Enrich.WithEnvironmentUserName()
                .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
                    .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware"))
                    .WriteTo.SQLite(GetFilePath("logs.db")))
                .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
                    .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource("Serilog.AspNetCore.RequestLoggingMiddleware"))
                    .WriteTo.File(GetFilePath("access.log"),rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,retainedFileCountLimit: 31))
                .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
                    .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(LogEvent => LogEvent.Exception != null)
                    .WriteTo.Seq("https://mylogger.appserver.com/"))
                .CreateLogger();

(Use Filter.ByExcluding to exclude a source)
